# node.js SQL Insert Into with array

Tags: sql, node.js

I'm new to Node.js and I've hit a roadblock I can't figure out. I'm trying to add an array to a SQL table using an INSERT INTO query.
Following the example [here][1] I see that I add a question mark as a placeholder for my values array, and the code takes care of the rest - but that doesn't seem to be working.

Here's the code:

```
var temp = [1,3,2];
conn2string= "INSERT INTO " + process.env.DB_TABLE + '(`0`, `1`, `2`) VALUES ? ';

let query = connection.query(conn2string, temp, function (err, result) { // this will insert in to data base  //[vals2[0]]
```

And the resulting SQL connection string is:

```
'INSERT INTO test(`0`, `1`, `2`) VALUES 1 `
```

What I'm expecting Is:

```
'INSERT INTO test(`0`, `1`, `2`) VALUES (1, 3, 2); `
```

Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest you to use some kind of query-builder, like http://knexjs.org/

Comment: Which database library are you using? `mysql`?

Comment: yes, i'm using mySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this with the `mysql` package, you need to wrap the `temp` variable inside an array. Remember to add the parentheses around the ? of the VALUES.

```
var temp = [1, 3, 2];
conn2string =
  "INSERT INTO " + process.env.DB_TABLE + "(`0`, `1`, `2`) VALUES (?) ";

let query = connection.query(conn2string, [temp], function (err, result) {
  
});
```

This is because the parameter after the SQL string expects an array whose elements match each `?` or `??` in the SQL string. By passing the `temp` array directly, you're essentially telling it that the first ? is 1, the second ? is 3, the third ? is 2. However, when you wrap the `temp` array in another array, you're essentially telling it that the value of the first ? is the `temp` array, and it formats it accordingly.

Comment: Hey, great explanation - even I could understand it! That worked well too, so thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a string value from array:

```
let query = connection.query(conn2string, '(' + temp.join(',') + ')', function (err, result) {
```

or, better, use full template:

```
var temp = [1,3,2];
conn2string= "INSERT INTO " + process.env.DB_TABLE + '(`0`, `1`, `2`) VALUES (?, ?, ?) ';
```

and to pass temp[0], temp[1], etc

or not to use a template:

```
conn2string= "INSERT INTO " + process.env.DB_TABLE + '(`0`, `1`, `2`) VALUES (' + temp[0] + ', ' + temp[1] + ', ' + temp[2] + ')';
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was hoping to be able to make the single question mark replaced with an array method work. The actual query I have is many many columns long, so embedding the data one way or another is not an option. Plan B is to build a query string, but the method of just using a single question mark was too simple to ignore.

Comment: Warning: you're exposing yourself to [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) by building the query without escaping the values or using bound parameters or a parameterized query.

Comment: of course you should care about it. I just gave options with predefined number values

Answer (score 0):

you can try embedded the data into sql string directly using this way:

```
conn2string= `INSERT INTO ${process.env.DB_TABLE} (`0`, `1`, `2`) VALUES (${temp.join(',')})`;
```

or I think you must insert n "?" like the numbert of element in array

Comment: Warning: you're exposing yourself to [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) by building the query without escaping the values or using bound parameters or a parameterized query.